# How do I display the IP address of a specific NIC card with visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ip-address

I am attempting to create a VB program that will allow me to easily set the IP address of the LAN on my laptop. The first thing I am trying to do is automatically load what the current address is when I open the program. I created a basic form and entered code that when I push the button, it searches the NIC's for the specific card name I specify and is supposed to then display the name and address.

The issue I am having is when I specify "Local Area Connection" it returns the correct name, but the address is "FFec0:0:0:ffff::3%1". The code works to some extent, because if I put in "Wireless Network Connection" as the desired card, it returns the correct IP address. Here is my code, could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Reqd_NIC_Name As String = "Local Area Connection"
    'Dim Reqd_NIC_Name As String = "Wireless Network Connection"

    Dim Alladapters As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    Dim adapter As NetworkInterface
    For Each adapter In Alladapters
        Dim adapterProps As IPInterfaceProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties()
        Dim IPCollection As IPAddressCollection = adapterProps.DnsAddresses
        If IPCollection.Count > 0 And adapter.Name.ToString = Reqd_NIC_Name Then
            Dim NICAddress As IPAddress
            For Each NICAddress In IPCollection
                Label3.Text = NICAddress.ToString
                Label4.Text = adapter.Name.ToString
            Next NICAddress
        End If
    Next adapter
End Sub
```

Comment: Those appear to be DNS Server address for a virtual Network Adapter.  I get the same thing when querying ip info with ipconfig /all.  The VMWare adapters all show similarly formatted strings for the DNS servers.

Comment: That's just a local Ipv6 address assigned as DNS. You're asking for the DNS addresses from the properties.